# Preloading SKTextureAtlases causes memory problems and crash

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, preloading, sktextureatlas

I'm making an adventure type game. While making this game I experienced memory leaks, so I decided to create a preloader, which I called SKPreloader.

In my GameViewController:

```
_preloader = [[SKPreloader alloc]init];
[_preloader setDelegate:self];
[_preloader preloadTextureAtlasesForScene:1];
```

In the SKPreloader:

```
(void)preloadTextureAtlas:(SKTextureAtlas *)atlas{
[atlas preloadWithCompletionHandler:^void {
    NSLog(@"laden...");
    if([atlas isEqual:_atlasFotoDistort]){
        NSLog(@"loaded foto");
        [self preloadTextureAtlas:_atlasFotoDistortWoman];
    }else if([atlas isEqual:_atlasFotoDistortWoman]){
        NSLog(@"loaded foto woman");
        [self preloadTextureAtlas:_atlasTV];
    }else if ([atlas isEqual:_atlasTV]){
        NSLog(@"loaded tv1");
        [self preloadTextureAtlas:_atlasTV2];
    }else if ([atlas isEqual:_atlasTV2]){
        NSLog(@"loaded tv2");
        [self preloadTextureAtlas:_atlasTV3];
    }else if ([atlas isEqual:_atlasTV3]){
        NSLog(@"loaded tv3");
        [self preloadTextureAtlas:_atlasDementia];
    }else if ([atlas isEqual:_atlasDementia]){
        NSLog(@"loaded dementia");
        [self preloadTextureAtlas:_atlasDementiaKeuken];
    }else if ([atlas isEqual:_atlasDementiaKeuken]){
        NSLog(@"loaded keuken");
        [self preloadTextureAtlas:_atlasGordijnLinks];
    }else if ([atlas isEqual:_atlasGordijnLinks]){
        NSLog(@"loaded gordijnlinks");
        [self preloadTextureAtlas:_atlasGordijnRechts];
    }else if ([atlas isEqual:_atlasGordijnRechts]){
        NSLog(@"loaded gordijnrechts");
        [self preloadTextureAtlas:_atlasHond];
    }else if ([atlas isEqual:_atlasHond]){
        NSLog(@"loaded hond");
        [self preloadTextureAtlas:_atlasHondKop];
    }else if ([atlas isEqual:_atlasHondKop]){
        NSLog(@"loaded hond kop");
        [self preloadRestOfTextureAtlasesForScene:1];
    }
}];
}


- (void)preloadRestOfTextureAtlasesForScene:(int)sceneNumber{

NSArray *arrayOfAtlases = [self restofTextureAtlasesForScene:sceneNumber];

[SKTextureAtlas preloadTextureAtlases:arrayOfAtlases withCompletionHandler:^void{
    NSLog(@"loaded all");
    [_delegate didFinishPreloading];
}];
}
```

The texts prefixed by _ are SKTextureAtlases.

The delegate is read in the GameViewController and starts the first scene. When the SKPreloader reaches the method preloadRestOfTextureAtlases, the memory usage is at 240mb and stays there which ultimately causes a crash.

Any help on how I could fix this problems and still preload the atlases?

Addition: the bigest atlas is 16mb. All the small atlases are preloaded in the last array.

Comment: I don't get why you preload another texture atlas from within an atlas' preload completion handler? You should really have a list of atlases that you want to preload, and preload them in sequence, done. Also be sure that any not currently needed atlases are allowed to dealloc properly (ie don't keep a strong ref to them) while ensuring that preloaded atlases stay in memory until they're being used by sprites (ie preloading but allowing atlas to deallocate immediately, then loading it again once the first sprite uses the atlas is a common issue in SK and incorrectly applied preloading).

Comment: I do that because I was afraid it would be too much memory if I did them all in one array. 
So, I don't make the properties strong in my SKPreloader.h then? I'm not sure how I enable the atlas to deallocate immediately and then loading it again when needed. Could you give me some more information? That would be really helpful.

Comment: An atlas deallocates when there's no strong reference holding on to it. Loading an atlas, keeping it in a strong ref but no sprite using it will waste memory, on the other hand preloading an atlas and not holding a strong ref to it (or creating at least one sprite using that atlas) can possibly unload the atlas right away, causing it to be loaded again when needed. Preloading is tricky to get right.